# How to Convert DirectX Texture2D to a DXGI Surface for WPF Rendering?

Tags: c#, directx, sharpdx, wpf

I have an image in my WPF application that uses a `D3DImage` to render DirectX content. On the DirectX side I render everything to a `Texture2D` using SharpDX (a C# DirectX wrapper), but I'm not sure how to convert the rendered texture to a `D3DImage`.

I found the `D3DImage.SetBackBuffer(D3DResourceType backBufferType, IntPtr backBuffer)` method, but that requires the texture to be a DXGI Surface. Here's the code I'm working with:

```
// renderTexture is a Texture2D that serves as the renderTarget for the DirectX content
// d3dimg is the D3DImage that WPF uses

d3dimg.Lock()
d3dimg.SetBackBuffer(D3DResourceType.IDirect3DSurface9, 
                     renderTexture.QueryInterface<Surface>().NativePointer);
d3dimg.Unlock();
```

But for some reason, the `SetBackBuffer` function call throws an exception saying that the "specified cast is not valid," even though I'm not doing any casts here (as far as I can see). What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Did you solve this? D3DImage only works with Direct3D 9Ex surface so it won't work with DXGI/Texture2D which are Direct3D 11... unless you arrange some very tricky DXGI surface sharing between 11 -> 9Ex in advance. I have all the numerous code fragments that prove this should be possible (i.e. accelerated Direct3D 11 video pipeline targeting WPF) but have struggled to fully stitch them together after months of work (albeit starting from zero Direct3D knowledge). Note that this form of surface sharing requires coordinating synchronization manually. In comparison, If you can switch to Direct3D 9 source everything works very easily.

The casting error you are getting is from inside the D3DImage, when it fails to cast your 11 surface to the Surface9Ex it expects and requires.

---

[edit: see my comment below for more information on a full solution]

Comment: If anyone is interested, I did eventually get a **DXGI/Direct3D11** video pipeline targeting **WPF** in **.NET 4.7** working in *Windows Media Foundation* `MediaSession` mode. This requires writing a custom `IMFMediaSink` that shunts to an integrated `D3DImage`. At first (by specifying `MF_SA_D3D11_SHARED_WITHOUT_MUTEX`), I was able to directly share each **DXGI** surface into D3D9 by calling `D3DImage.SetBackBuffer()` once per frame, but later moved to a manual D3D11 `CopyResource` into my own `ID3D11Texture2D1` because it allows for the less-thrashy use of `D3DImage.AddDirtyRect()` instead.

Comment: Forgot to mention, the code is 100% **C#**. As some will know, a huge part of the challenge with *Windows Media Foundation* is getting its endless infinitude of COM interfaces (`IMFMediaSink` for starters, in this case) on semi-free-threaded COM instances--including assorted asynchronous callbacks--working property in pure managed code. Same goes for `DXGI` and `Direct3D11`, for which there are managed interop libraries out there, but in this case I ended up just rolling my own so that I could design the **p/Invoke** marshaling around the exact needs of this scenario.

Comment: One more detail that might help people working in this space: A big problem you confront in replacing the EVR model, which is what is required here, is that it initially appears that you then take on the responsibility of handling uncompressed video and de-interlacing it, etc., tasks which were not your burden in the old D3D9 "custom presenter." A breakthrough here was the obscure Media Foundation attribute `MF_TOPOLOGY_ENABLE_XVP_FOR_PLAYBACK`. When asserted on your `IMFTopology`, a conversion MFT is added to the pipeline to handle the conversions, which hugely simplifies your `IMFMediaSink`.

Comment: Is the code available somewhere?

Comment: @DanielB Unfortunately not quite yet. But I consider the managed **WPF** app very stable and successful and actually use it exclusively--and heavily--as my own favorite full-time media player. I'm happy to discuss the details more, but you should realize that even in **C#** (or perhaps because of it--there's a certain weird productivity trade-off here)--it's a complex task overall. Please create an attached chat discussion for this question if you wish to discuss further.

Comment: I've started a [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/93336/how-to-convert-directx-texture2d-to-a-dxgi-surface-for-wpf-rendering).

Comment: @DanielB Checking up on the progress of your project. In particular, your last comment (in the chat) regarding an `AnyCPU` implementation of `IMFMediaSink` for WPF. It still seems to be my specialty, considering that every time I google for more research, I only find my own posts. It's clear that DWM is the big gorilla in this arena, so I'm now looking into the [waitable swap chain](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/gaming/reduce-latency-with-dxgi-1-3-swap-chains) support that was added to Windows **8.1**. See also: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=E3wTajGZOsA

Comment: Currently there is no progress on that due to more important tasks. Would be great to see your implementation.

Comment: @GlennSlayden Any updates on the source code for this? I also want to use Directx11 with D3DImage. At least if you could post an answer here with the custom IMFMediaSink  would be super helpful for a lot of people

Comment: @GlennSlayden I've sent you an invitation in LinkedIn